# Looking for easy to read Mathematics/Statistics Journals

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, recreational-mathematics

I am currently a third year Statistics Major<sup>1</sup> and have been browsing through my universities journal libraries and find it quite hard to get a foothold in what writers of these journals are talking about as the material assumes that readers have familiarity of the concepts discussed.

Does anyone know of any Mathematical/Statistical journals which do not assume a very strong base in mathematics/Statistics from the readers but will which provide interesting content for readers and demonstrate interesting applications of the concepts discussed?

<sup>1 <sub>*Please save the comments about how its not "Real Mathematics"*</sub></sup>

Comment: If you are looking for journals, it's tough. But you can always start with magazines! The American Statistician is one. However, you can surely start with the old Statistics journals, like those of 1930-1940. Much of the statistics today was developed then.

Comment: The Mathematical Gazette is usually a fun read.

Answer (score 0):

Crux Mathematicorum is a wonderful Mathematics journal. Browse through this [page](https://cms.math.ca/crux/)